# A subject close to my heart

Tags: terminology

What are the differences between: [subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_%28grammar%29), [subjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjective_%28grammar%29), [nominative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nominative), and the [nominative case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_case)? If there aren't any substantial ones, why are there so many terms for basically saying the same thing?

Comment: Good question. And don't forget "progressive" and "continuous"!

Comment: @Pitarou this is only the abridged version of my original question :)

Comment: The only time I knew anything about 'nominative' was when studying Latin. The one I could never get the hang of was Vocative. 'Et tu Brute' - but why?

Comment: The Vocative is used only with names, only in direct address, and only in the second declension. It's irrelevant to anything else; it's like English _MYself_ but _HIMself_: a minor irregularity that affects nothing.

Comment: @John, the vocative is not only used with names. It is, in most Western European languages that have it, only morphologically distinct in certain _declensions_, but it operates across those declensions, in both names and regular nouns; while it fails to operate in other declensions, whether names or regular nouns.

Comment: Yes, but direct address only occurs with human speech partners, so it **is** restricted to nouns denoting humans, most of which are names.

Comment: @JohnLawler So, what is the case when I say "OK Google" to trigger Google Voice Search?

Comment: @Pitarou *Personification*

Comment: English has no cases. If you were speaking Latin, you would use the Vocative case form of _Google_, whatever that might have been. BTW, note that _Google_ is a name.

Comment: @JohnLawler If English has no cases, and it's not the first time I have heard this argument, why do so many on EL&U speak about the accusative, nominative, dative and the vocative case? Is Latin to "blame" or do grammarians and linguists really use these terms?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I just explained that in a comment on the answer below, because Susan asked the same question. Grammarians and linguists (same group, actually; there are no grammarians who are not linguists) do use those terms, but nor for English. For Latin, sure; for German, Russian, Greek, Sanskrit, sure; they're inflected. English isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Nominative*** and ***(the) nominative case*** mean the same thing. It's just a normal shortening of a noun compound, like *future* and *the future tense*, *optative* and *the optative mood*, *middle* and *the middle voice*. These are all technical names for grammatical phenomena, none of which occur in English.

***Subjective*** means the opposite of *objective*; i.e, a subjective judgement is not objective. If you see it used as a grammatical term in a discussion of grammar, it's a sign that the author is parroting opinions instead of facts. It's not a grammatical term used by grammarians, but it used to be part of old handwaving terminology like "subjective complement".

> There **are** *subject complements* and *object complements,* but they're types of noun clauses functioning as subject or object; this is not the same thing at all as any of the phenomena that used to be called "subjective complements".

***Subject*** is a grammatical relation. In English and most non-ergative languages, there are three possible grammatical relations: *subject, direct object,* and *indirect object*.

These three are the usual linguistic reflexes of the arguments of intransitive, transitive, and bitransitive predicates in [predicate calculus](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf):

1. `DEAD` (*Bill*)
2. `READ` (*Bill, book*)
3. `GIVE` (*Bill, book, Mary*)

English requires every clause to have a subject (even if it isn't there, it must be attributable); every transitive clause has a direct object as well; every bitransitive clause has both, plus an indirect object.

> These are often just called *1, 2,* and *3* by Relational Grammarians; e.g, the dative alternation is stated in RG as *Promote 3 to 2*, while Passive is *Promote 2 to 1*.

Comment: I have heard others here say there isn't a [nominative](http://englishguide.us/pronouns/pronoun-nominative-or-subjective-case) or accusative case in English. If that's true, why are there references to it?

Comment: @Susan: Because it used to be fashionable to project properties of Latin grammar (like future and perfect tenses, or subjunctive mood) onto English grammar -- Latin grammar being the ideal, of course -- and Latin does have a nominative and an accusative case. As Old English had, and as German still has. But no one has ever found more than 5 words in Modern English that are accusative, and they're all pronouns. A real case system encompasses every noun in the language (or almost every -- Latin neuter nouns collapse the nominative and the accusative case forms).

Comment: I disagree with you about  "subjective" and "objective". For instance, I knew a man who first learnt English use the terms "subjective" and "objective" in the way that others might use "nominative" and "accusative".

Comment: @JohnLawler - Thanks for the answer. I believe you of course; your explanation makes perfect sense (and reminds me of classicism). I taught Latin a number of years ago, and I can't seem to undo those useful (to me) frames of reference. It's always been useful to think of "predicate nominatives", or accusative for DO and OOPs.

Comment: If you actually know Latin, it's harmless, and in fact that's where all this stuff came from. English grammar has never been taught in English classes -- they're only composition and literature, no language. When everybody going to college took Latin in HS, they could look at English and say "Oh, I see how **that** works". But nowadays people just mouth the words and identify the Partes Orationis and think they've learned grammar. Sad.