# Why verb tenses names are so-called?

Tags: verbs, tenses

I'm new to this community. Why verb tenses names are so-called? For example why do <strike>we</strike> some people say "Present simple" <strike>instead of</strike>  where others say "Simple present", and so on.

Comment: I think your premise is incorrect, as per @Bahaa's answer. But I'm not closevoting because someone may have something useful to say about the arguments for and against each different word order that *does* occur in such contexts.

Comment: Thank you! Do you recommend editing my question?

Comment: I've made a change using "strikethrough" so my first comment still makes sense. But if you don't like the way I've done it, please feel free to "revert" to the original or edit it yourself.

Comment: It's ok. I didn't know that "Simple Present" is legal before! Thank you!

Comment: related: [A subject close to my heart](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149335/a-subject-close-to-my-heart)

Answer (score 4):

English verbs have 5 controlling factors:

Voice: active or passive

Tense: past (preterite) or present

Aspect1: recently completed (perfect) or not

Aspect2: uncompleted (progressive) or not

Mood: actual or hypothetical(the modal auxiliaries)

Each of these features is binary (not counting the different modals), so there are 32 different ways to state a verb (not counting the infinitive).

'**Simple**' means that the 2 Aspect options are 'off'.
The ordering of the options is not important (- we don't yet know how the brain does it).

Comment: Thank you! I'm not a native English speaker, can you make it more clear, please?

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib Aml's answer is among the clearest and simplest I've seen on this topic. If some parts are still unclear to you, you need to tell Aml which parts you'd like more information on. Otherwise you're asking him to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

When we describe tenses in English, we usually put *past*, *present* and *future* before *simple* and *perfect* which will precede *continuous (progressive)*, for example:

> Present Perfect Continuous (Not Perfect Continuous Present or Continuous Perfect Present)
>   Past Perfect Continuous (Not Perfect Continuous Past or Continuous Perfect Past)

However, if you replace *Perfect* with *Simple* in the above examples, we don't usually use *Simple* as it is not absolutely required, for example:

> Present Continuous
>   Past Continuous
>   Present Perfect
>   Past Perfect

As Aml explained, *Simple* just indicates there is no aspect of *Perfect* and *Continuous*, in other words, *Present Simple* means *Present without Perfect and Continuous*.

Present Simple and Simple Present have the same meaning and whichever you use is not likely to cause confusion.